# Fetch data from four tables

Tags: sql

How can I fetch data from four tables?

I have four tables:

- **Article_Table** (`ArticleName, ArticleNumber`)
- **IndexDetails_Table** (`IndexSubMasterId, ArticleNumber`)
- **IndexSubMaster_Table** (`IndexSubMasterId, IndexMasterId`)
- **IndexMaster_Table** (`IndexMasterId, Keyword`)

I need final output:

```
ArticleName  from Article table.
```

I will provide you a `Keyword` as an input parameter.

The process which I need would be:

1. `IndexMasterId From IndexMaster_Table where Keyword = 'bl'`
2. `IndexSubMasterId From IndexSubMaster_Table

   Where IndexSubMaster_Table.IndexMasterId = IndexMaster_Table.IndexMasterId`
3. `ArticleNumber From IndexDetails_Table 
   Where IndexDetails_Table.IndexSubMasterId = IndexSubMaster_Table.IndexSubMasterId`
4. `ArticleName From Article_Table

   Where Article_Table.ArticleNumber = IndexDetails_Table.ArticleNumber`

Comment: is this related to iPhone ? I dont think so

Comment: This is not related to iphone. sorry!!!!

Comment: @SauravSinha: though am nt clearly understand your question, let me knw you want select query to get articlename form Article_Table ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this I am sure there are more efficient ways but here is something for you

```
Declare @keyword varchar(20)
Set @keyword = 'bl'

Select article.ArticleName FROM IndexMaster_Table masterTable
JOIN IndexSubMaster_Table subMaster
on masterTable.IndexMasterId = subMaster.IndexMasterId
JOIN IndexDetails_Table details
on details.IndexSubMasterId = subMaster.IndexSubMasterId
JOIN Article_Table article
on article.ArticleNumber = details.ArticleNumber
Where masterTable.keyword = @keyword
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie.This approach working perfectly and taking less time to execute.